# How can I create a hover sheen effect on a specific part of a background URL

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have a background image URL set on my homepage.

I would like to know how I might go about creating a hover sheen effect on a *specific part* of the background url.

Im curious to know if this is achievable given that I am not styling any anchor elements.

[image]

> home.html.erb

```
<%= content_for :head do %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "home" %>
<% end %>

<div class="jumbotron center">
    <h1>Japanese and South Korean luxury Skincare!</h1>
    <p>
      <%= link_to "MOISTURISERS", pins_path, class: "btn btn-pink btn-lg" %>
      <%= link_to "CLEANSERS", "#", class: "btn btn-info btn-lg" %>
      <%= link_to "TREATMENTS", "#", class: "btn btn-info btn-lg" %>
    </p>    
</div>
```

> application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>SampleApp</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => false %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => false %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <%= yield :head %>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,700|Lobster' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>

    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <div class="container">
    <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
     <%= content_tag(:div, msg, class: "alert alert-#{name}") %>
    <% end %>
    <%= yield %>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: thank you for the note, I am new to the front end stuff and don't have that yet. Do you want me to provide any HTML or CSS. Is this technically impossible

Comment: yes provide them then it would be easier to solve

Comment: Will that make a difference though given that I am not manipulating any elements or anchors

Comment: ok tell me that the white area containing  "Japanese and Sou.." is a div or is a part of image ?

Comment: <div class="jumbotron centre"> But I am not trying to style that, its the creme on the ladies face which is part of the background url

Comment: well my Idea is to put a div with transparent background over the cream area with irregular shape and then provide hover to it. I'll tell you if I could make it.

Comment: would appreciate that, I could provide the background url

Comment: give me the original image

Comment: 2 minutes and il source thanks.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/u3hdrld63xxluak/japan%20copy.png?dl=0

Comment: hey I am getting 404 error

Comment: my apologies try this. https://www.dropbox.com/s/u3hdrld63xxluak/japan%20copy.png?dl=0

Answer (score 3):

You could use some sort of keyframe animation with a gradient to achieve some sort of shine effect. Altering the `animation` timing will allow a faster/slower animation duration, and the keyframes can also be altered themselves to give a more appropriate effect.

```css
.background-image {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  background: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1582650448629-3c854f356544?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1074&q=80');
  background-size:100% 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.shine {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  height: 200vw;
  border-radius:50%;
  width: 200vw;
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.6) 50%, transparent 100%);
  opacity:0;
}
.background-image:hover .shine{
  animation: shine 1s linear forwards 1;
  }
@keyframes shine {

  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 25%;
    left: 25%;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    top: -100%;
    left: -100%;
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="background-image">
  <span class="shine"></span>
</div>
```

<sup>Vendor Prefixes removed for clarity.</sup>

Comment: appreciate your input, the code snippet you provided is not running

Comment: yes please that would be very helpful to incorporate the original image

Comment: This is only a matter of altering the `background` property. As for 'it's not working', you may need to include vendor prefixes to support various browsers.

Comment: the only query i have pertains to your div class="background image". I am not importing the url currently using that on my home.html.erb I am pulling the japan image straight from the CSS.

Comment: please see my updated code above sir. thank you very much